# How to inactive or broadcast message to particular app version users?

Tags: android, google-play, versioning

We frequently release app on playstore by upgrading versions.

We caught in issue recently. Our app has 3 environments QA, Staging and Production.  Before release on play store we set app environment as "Production".

But last time with "QA" environment, app went on play store with version (1.8.2). And after that two more release went on play store with version (1.8.3 and 1.9.0) respectively.

I want to give message to all users who has 1.8.2 version. So those can immediate get latest version and get proper data.

Question is...
1. Is there any way to inform users who have particular version?
2. Is there any way to inactive 1.8.2?

Comment: Well if you do not have email addresses, some sort of cloud messaging implemented or remote messaging - I would say no.

Comment: If you did not implement a way to send message to the users in your app, then there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not implemented messaging in your app then there is no way. This is why it is a good idea to use a product like [Firebase remote config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) in your app which gives you a good way of rolling out configuration changes like this. And Firebase would make it very easy to add this sort of messaging system to your App.